# GWT - RichTextArea - how to set its inner font-family

Tags: gwt

I am just wondering how can I change RichTextArea inner font-family or font-size for example?
I tried to modify its CSS something as a

```
 border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
```

... but it doesn't work :( The font is still something like times new roman or something this way :S

So is there a way manually set its font attributes?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988118/java-gwt-richtextarea-change-font-family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Formatter`, documented here: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.Formatter.html#setFontName(java.lang.String).

It abstracts all the styling stuff so you don't have to manually write CSS.