# java gwt richtextarea change font-family

Tags: java, gwt, fonts

The Object richtextarea of java gwt has as default the font-family 'times new roman' is it somehow possible to change the family to 'Arial'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several options. You can create a CSS class and set it on the body element of the document inside RichTextArea, or you can set the style attribute on it directly. If you want this change to be consistent throughout your app, I recommend creating a new class and adding an InitializeHandler to it.

```
public class MyRichTextArea extends RichTextArea {

    public MyRichTextArea() {

        addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent ie) {

                Document document = IFrameElement.as(getElement()).getContentDocument();
                BodyElement body = document.getBody();
                body.setAttribute("style", "font-family: Arial Unicode MS,Arial,sans-serif;");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but that doesn't work, I also tried to set it with: richTextArea.setStyleName("font-family: Arial Black");

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my app. setStyleName, on the other hand, obviously won't work as it sets the style on the RichTextArea itself, not on the document which it contains.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use the provided functionality.
If you want to change it at creation time, you will need the initializeHandler as mentioned in answer 1:

```
RichTextArea rta = new RichTextArea();
rta.addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {
    public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent event) {
            rta.getFormatter().setFontName("\"Trebuchet MS\",Trebuchet,Arial");
            rta.getFormatter().setFontSize(FontSize.SMALL);
            rta.getFormatter().setForeColor("#FF0000");
        }
    });
```

PS: you need to do this before you add any content to the textarea, or it will only be applied to new input.

Comment: Since answer order can change with voting, it's more useful to refer to another answer by the user who posted it, rather than its number.

Comment: This is the WRONG answer - it will set a new style on the selected text only, not on all of the RichTextArea's contents as specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found more common solution:

```
addInitializeHandler(new InitializeHandler() {
        public void onInitialize(InitializeEvent ie) {
            Document document = IFrameElement.as(getElement()).getContentDocument(); 
            BodyElement body = document.getBody(); 
            HeadElement head = HeadElement.as(Element.as(body.getPreviousSibling())); 
            LinkElement styleLink = document.createLinkElement(); 
            styleLink.setType("text/css"); 
            styleLink.setRel("stylesheet"); 
            styleLink.setHref("richtextarea.css"); 
            head.appendChild(styleLink);
        } 
    });
```

After adding initialization handler, it's easy to change styles in `richtextarea.css` file